# Text color in kivy Dropdown menu

Tags: python, kivy

So I'm trying to color some text in a dropdown menu and my part of code currently looks like this:

```
DropDown:

        id: dropdown
        on_select: btn.text = '{}'.format(args[1])

        Button:
            text: '[color=333333]Some Text which is Black[/color]'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '24dp'
            width:'130dp'
            on_release: dropdown.select('Some Text i dont know how to color')
            markup: True
```

If I try to add [color=333333]...[/color] in the release command it doesnt color the text but instead shows the tags. 
Anybody knows how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `markup: True` to the main button.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder


runTouchApp(Builder.load_string("""
Screen:

    Button:
        id: btn
        text: 'Hello'
        size_hint: None, None
        markup: True
        height: '24dp'
        width: '200dp'
        on_release: dropdown.open(self)

    Widget:
        on_parent: dropdown.dismiss()

    DropDown:
        id: dropdown
        on_select: btn.text = '{}'.format(args[1])

        Button:
            text: 'My first Item'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '24dp'
            on_release: dropdown.select(self.text)
        Label:
            text: '[color=ff3333]Unselectable item[/color]'
            markup: True
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '24dp'
        Button:
            text: 'My second Item'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '24dp'
            on_release: dropdown.select(self.text)
        Button:
            markup: True
            text: '[color=ff3333]Hello[/color] [color=3333ff]World[/color]'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '24dp'
            on_release: dropdown.select(self.text)
        Button:
            markup: True
            text: '[color=333333]Some Text which is Black[/color]'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '24dp'
            on_release: dropdown.select(self.text)
"""))
```

## Output

[image: Dropdown opened]
[image: Hello World selected]